# Automapper don't map null sources

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I'm using an Automapper and I need to map a List of objects into a nested object. I have these objects:

```
public abstract class FooSrcBase
{
}

public class FooSrc : FooSrcBase
{
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}

public class FooDest
{
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}

public class FooDestGroup
{
    public FooDest FooDest { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public FooDestGroup FooDestGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I have `IEnumerable<FooSrc>` which contains `FooSrc` objects (there are many implementations and only one object per each type may exist in the source) and I need to map it into `Dest` object. I need this because of mapping into the view models for front end.

When I register mapping like this:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<FooSrc>, Dest>().ForPath(dest => dest.FooDestGroup.FooDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FooSrc))));

CreateMap<FooSrc, FooDest>();
```

When I map empty list, a problem occurs in `Dest` object - `FooDestGroup` is an instance of object, which has a property `FooDest` with `null` value.

How it would be possible to make `Dest` property `FooDestGroup` map to `null`, if I provide empty list as a source?

Comment: You can avoid `ForPath`. Rewrite your maps so you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<FooSrcBase>, Dest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FooDestGroup, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FooSrc))));

CreateMap<FooSrc, FooDestGroup>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FooDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

CreateMap<FooSrc, FooDest>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your abstract `FooSrc` class will need a different name (conflicts with your concrete class name `FooSrc`)

How about modifying the constructor on Dest to avoid the nesting issue?
Automapper is capable of mapping to the constructor parameter automatically, but if you need more advanced behaviour you can refer to https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html

Something like this should work:

```
public class Dest
{
    public FooGroup FooGroup { get; set; }

    public Dest(FooDest fooDest) 
    {
        FooGroup = new FooGroup { FooDest = fooDest };
    }
}

[..]

Mapper.CreateMap<FooSrc, Dest>();

Mapper.Map<List<Dest>>(listOfFooSrc);
```

Comment: I've answered with my solution, which doesn't need changing the constructor